# Ubuntu 15.04 checking an ext4 partition on every boot

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, fsck

I have gone through other posts similar to my question, but i tried all solutions/ or their methods dont apply to my case.

There is no /forcefsck file on my system.

`/etc/fstab` contents:

```
UUID=6206c47e-b5aa-424f-876d-3c72889098b3 /     ext4    errors=remount-ro 0    1
UUID=caff3891-1cff-451f-8ab9-f5c074aa4dbc /home ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID=886f5731-2180-44cb-a46c-82b619bed4bd none  swap    sw                0    0
```

I did fsck with liveboot session on all ext4 partitions,and specially my main `/home` partition but didn't get any errors whatsoever.Ran this command: result no errors.

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sdb2
```

SMART check output:

```
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdb smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002
[x86_64-linux-3.19.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION === SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Serial Number:    S2TTJ9HC801807
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 208283fbf
Firmware Version: 2AR10001
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Aug  2 07:50:04 2015 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

---

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb2
```

[output here](http://pastebin.com/ufEECmjt)

But still, `/dev/sdb2` (`/home`) gets checked every single time I do a reboot.

Any help?

PS: I've been getting this prompt very often on resuming the notebook from sleep.

[image]

There have been other users reporting about the annoyance of this dialog on the internet, with no clear explanation what this dialog is all about. This started appearing only when I upgraded to 15.04.
Can this be related to my fsck problem?

Comment: Hello!
I have exaclty the same issue. I lost half of a day googling around and I found nothing. After installing 15.04 I have to wait 1-2 min to make fsck on every boot. It was not happening on 14.10. Let me know when you find the answer

Comment: Is all UUID in fstab correct? Check this post. http://askubuntu.com/questions/675316/fsck-on-every-bootup-slow-bootup-moved