# Fsck on every bootup, slow bootup, moved /

Tags: boot, partitioning, fsck

Today I started experiencing an annoying issue. When I boot to Ubuntu 15.04, it runs fsck on one disk every time. I've located the cause to this problem on my `/home` partition, which is located at `/dev/sda5`. After disabling it's bootup fsck completely from `/etc/fstab`, it no longer runs fsck on any disk. The partition appears clean even without running fsck.

Also after disabling the fsck procedure (this was also taking a lot of time before getting rid of fsck), Ubuntu takes a really long time to boot up (1m 30s), even though `/` is on an SSD.

Just to mix this up a little, I just moved my root-partition to the SSD mentioned above. The fsck-issue was occurring before I did this, but the slow boot-up did not.

Here's my `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5`: http://pastebin.com/8fr7ZWCk
Please inform me of any other info/logs I should include.

**EDIT:**

Looking at `dmesg` output, I saw this rather time-consuming task:

```
[    7.019883] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[    7.020394] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
[    7.020611] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
[    7.020736] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
[   96.330932] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored # this one is taking very long
[   96.348967] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   96.348969] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   96.348972] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   96.352761] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
```

I just noticed that my swap-partition was referenced to a wrong UID in fstab. I changed that (and also reinstalled my NVidia drivers), and now the system boots in just seven seconds!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the cause of my issue.

In `/etc/fstab`, the swap partition was referencing a non-existing partition UID. I updated it, and now my system boots just fine!

Answer (score 6):

More specifically for anyone who finds this with the error, in your `/etc/fstab` there should be all your drives with their mounted directories. At the end of every disk line, there are two numbers. IF the second number is either 2, or 1, it will do a different level of a Fs-check.

If you don't want an `fs-check` to run on every boot, set both numbers at the end to 0. That's it. Then save and reboot. No more Fs-check!

Comment: Yup! For some reason, after fixing the swap-partition reference in /etc/fstab, fsck is no longer run even if I allow it as you specified.

Comment: @ollpu Hmm, it may be disabled in your settings

Comment: And now it's running it again (and taking 9 precious seconds)! Something weird is going on...

Answer (score -1):

To me, the solution was edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg (after have done a copy, sure), I found the line that contains linux /boot/vmlinuz + YOUR KERNEL VERSION, and add on end of line fastboot. After I execute sudo update-grub. Done, fsck isn't executing more on startup.
Of course, it's a little dangerous if you don't have a script to execute fsck with some frequency.

Comment: -1 `update-grub` overwrites any previous changes to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. If you want to edit the kernel boot parameters, edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry in `/etc/default/grub`, then run `sudo update-grub`.